# Why isnt My PHP code updating SQL

Tags: php, sql

Does anyone know why this PHP code isn't updating the column `pictures`it will update the rest of them but just not the pictures column it is to update users information So email address , password and picture I'm Quite new to PHP so I dont really know what to look for when im looking for Errors

```
    <?php 

    require("common.php"); 

    if(empty($_SESSION['user'])) 
    { 
        header("Location: login.php"); 

        die("Redirecting to login.php"); 
    } 

    if(!empty($_POST)) 
    { 
        if(!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) 
        { 
            die("Invalid E-Mail Address"); 
        } 

        if($_POST['email'] != $_SESSION['user']['email']['picture']) 
        { 
            $query = " 
                SELECT 
                    1 
                FROM users 
                WHERE 
                    email = :email
                    picture = :picture
            "; 

            $query_params = array( 
                ':email' => $_POST['email'] 
            ); 

            try 
            { 
                $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
                $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
            } 
            catch(PDOException $ex) 
            { 
                die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
            } 

            $row = $stmt->fetch(); 
            if($row) 
            { 
                die("This E-Mail address is already in use"); 
            } 
        } 

        if(!empty($_POST['password'])) 
        { 
            $salt = dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)) . dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)); 
            $password = hash('sha256', $_POST['password'] . $salt); 
            for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++) 
            { 
                $password = hash('sha256', $password . $salt); 
            } 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            $password = null; 
            $salt = null; 
        } 

        $query_params = array( 
            ':email' => $_POST['email'], 
            ':user_id' => $_SESSION['user']['id'], 
            ':picture' => $_POST['picture'], 
        ); 

        if($password !== null) 
        { 
            $query_params[':password'] = $password; 
            $query_params[':salt'] = $salt; 
        } 

        $query = " 
            UPDATE users 
            SET 
                email = :email 
                picture = :picture
        "; 

        if($password !== null) 
        { 
            $query .= " 
                , password = :password 
                , salt = :salt 
            "; 
        } 

        $query .= " 
            WHERE 
                id = :user_id 
        "; 

        try 
        { 
            // Execute the query 
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
        } 
        catch(PDOException $ex) 
        { 
            die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
        } 

        $_SESSION['user']['email']['picture'] = $_POST['email']; 

        header("Location: private.php"); 

        die("Redirecting to private.php"); 
    } 

?>
```

Comment: +1 for actually using prepared statements and validating input

Comment: You need to add a comma between `email=:email picture=:picture`. Are you checking the `$_POST['picture']` is set?

Comment: Also needs an AND in the WHERE clause of the SELECT, no?

Comment: Your SELECT query has two parameters in in, `:email` and `:picture`; but you're only binding `:email`.

Comment: I think your/a problem is the fact that your column name `1` is a single digit `SELECT 1 FROM users` and I quote *"`Identifiers may begin with a digit but unless quoted may not consist solely of digits.`"* --- [from the MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/identifiers.html) @user3116240

Comment: Try using backticks to wrap your `1` which might work.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a `,`.

```
$query = " 
    UPDATE users 
    SET 
        email = :email 
        picture = :picture
";
```

You need to change it to

```
$query = " 
    UPDATE users 
    SET 
        email = :email, 
        picture = :picture
";
```

Answer (score 2):

Your missing a comma after :email in your UPDATE statement.

```
$query = " 
            UPDATE users 
            SET 
                email = :email 
                picture = :picture
        ";
```

should be

```
$query = " 
        UPDATE users 
        SET 
            email = :email,  
            picture = :picture
    ";
```

EDIT: In addition to this you are also missing a parameter in your first query:

```
        $query = " 
            SELECT 
                1 
            FROM users 
            WHERE 
                email = :email
                picture = :picture
        "; 

        $query_params = array( 
            ':email' => $_POST['email'] 
        );
```

Notice how you are only applying :email in your query paramaters, but your query is expecting both :email and :picture.

You either need to remove `picture = :picture` from the `$query` or add `':picture' => $_POST['picture']` to `$query_params`

Comment: Ok,I have just updated it and it stil dosnt seem to be working

Comment: Check to make sure your form input has `name="picture"`, spelled correctly.  Are you sure `picture` isn't a file?

Comment: Try a var_dump($_POST['picture']) just before the $query statement and  see what the value is.

Comment: @Matt I have Just added a `var_dump($_POST['picture'])` and it is Giving me the Error white screen

Comment: The variable is likely empty. Check your html to see if you have an input name="picture"

Comment: Seems like the variable is empty, verify your HTML as @Leng mentioned above.

Comment: I Realised it wasn't linked to the correct file now its saying `Failed to run query: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens`

Comment: I'm guessing that is happening with the first SELECT query. You have :email and :picture, but your only giving it :email.

Comment: So I need to Change `SELECT 1` to `SELECT 2`?